# Font Awesome Icons Not Displaying In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome

I'm not a programmer.

I've been building sites using WordPress for a few years without any knowledge of programming.

Recently I changed to cloud hosting and two sites that I've built using WordPress are not displaying some of the font awesome icons.

I'm using Google Chrome to view my sites on as l build them. I was directed to this forum for help with this issue. I've read some of the answers related to this issue on this forum but since I am not a programmer l can't make sense of it.

I know how to search for the code in the editor area of WordPress but am not sure what code to change to fix this issue.

Is anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link in your header file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Add it to **header.php** file in add between **script** tag.